# Unable to center google maps iframe into a php section file of wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I inserted a google maps iframe into a php section file of wordpress theme.
Tried many ways to center it. Nothing worked so far!
Can you help?

Here's how it looks: http://prntscr.com/hjyd4s

```
     <div class="home-section-content

<!--
<div id="google-maps">  <!-- <div style=" margin:auto; ">
<style type="text/css"> 
#google-maps  {
mar gin: auto;
width: 125%;
border: 3px solid #73AD21;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}       
</style>
-->
            <br><br><br>

    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2989.608839663209!2d-8.163739!3d41.4693985!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd24e87671374bf1%3A0x9a3a665c9521b5a4!2sR.+de+S%C3%A3o+Mateus+193%2C+4820-500+Ascens%C3%A3o!5e0!3m2!1sen!2spt!4v1511832699133" 
     width="1400" height="800" ali gn="center" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div>
```

I commented out that piece of code you see, as it did not work. But you might point why?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `id="google-maps"` on the iframe itself, it's easier to center.

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
    #google-maps  {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px auto;
      border: 0
    }    
    </style>

    <div>
        <iframe id="google-maps" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2989.608839663209!2d-8.163739!3d41.4693985!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd24e87671374bf1%3A0x9a3a665c9521b5a4!2sR.+de+S%C3%A3o+Mateus+193%2C+4820-500+Ascens%C3%A3o!5e0!3m2!1sen!2spt!4v1511832699133" 
         width="1400" height="800" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: It works on a standalone html file but not on the php file in the theme.
It just does not center it!

Is there a way to force it?

Comment: It means some other CSS is probably conflicting with that. Can you inspect the element and check if there's anything? Or would you mind sharing the link to that wordpress site, so we can take a look?

Comment: I'd say either the div that contains the iframe is not full width, or there's a float somewhere.

Comment: I don't mind at all to share the url.
But i've noticed the theme which is bootstrap ready, is all broken when i view it on my phone.
It seems when you customize directly some php and css files you break things.

Displays ok on my PC monitor but not on the mobile!